# How to show password while typing?

Tags: settings, password

*Samsung Galaxy Ace 2 (there is no such tag, and I have too little reputation here to create it).*

On LG L5 when I type password I can see in the edit box the last character I typed. Better something than nothing.

However, with Ace 2 the story is worse -- all I see is sequence of dots, and I have real difficulties to type anything correctly.

**Question** -- how to show the password while typing?

Comment: I doubt that it's possible if the app does not have a "show password" checkbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not have your phone model on hand to try, but you can give this [link](http://www.butterscotch.com/tutorial/How-To-Turn-On-Visible-Passwords-On-Your-Android-Phone) a shot.

Generally, just go to Settings > Security > check Make passwords visible. This is true for my phone (HTC Desire, BCM 4.0.4).

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks! In my case it was even worse, it was buried at the bottom, under settings for lock screen ;-)